# Access 2013 maximized form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, maximize

I have a problem in an Access app. I open a form and its On Open event sets it to maximized. All good. From this form I click a button that opens another form who's On Open event opens it as maximized, over top of the original form. All good. When I close the second form, the original form is no longer maximized, it is now in a window. Not good.

I can't figure out why this is or how to prevent/resolve this. What event do I need to monitor and method to call to set the original form back to maximized. I tried playing with the On Close event of the second form but couldn't find the code to alter the (already open) original form. I tried a bunch of things but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, bit of a breakthrough. What fixed it was to place DoCmd.Maximize inside the **On Activate** event of the first form. When the 2nd form is closed the 1st form is automatically activated and the On Activate event fires, which maximizes the form again (I'm still not really sure why this is necessary). The key was figuring our what event to base the maximize method on.

Many thanks to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 1):

Set the property of both forms to pop-up,modular and you should be fine

Comment: As I understand it, the forms should be maximized *inside* the Access window, not globally. Maximized popup forms are not very user-friendly.

Comment: I have made many access database and almost all of them have a pop-up maximised form. I prefer this approach becuase the user then can't see the access window and the access application have the look and feel of a stand alone application. Often I will have a main form (maximised, pop-up) which contain a menu subform and a main-subform. Clicking on the buttons in the menu subform changes the form displayed in the main -subform control. The form in the main subform control sometime have buttons that causes other form to pop up modular. This approach works well and is very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `DoCmd.Maximize` in the Open event of the first form?

Then somewhere in the Close or Unload event of the second form (or somewhere else), there must be a `DoCmd.Restore`.

Is any of the forms Popup or Modal?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The forms are not popup or modular. Both use DoCmd.Maximize in the Open event. Adding DoCmd.Restore to the Close or Unload event of the second form has no affect, but I would have thought this action would be needed against the first form, since that is the one that needs restoring? I can't figure out how to execute code against the first form to have that affect, once the second form has closed. If I access the form using the Forms object as I close the 2nd form there is no command to change the window behaviour.

Comment: MSDN states "When you maximize a window in Access, all other windows are also maximized when you open them or switch to them..." but this seems not to be true.

Comment: That was a misunderstanding (sorry for being unclear): If there *was* a `DoCmd.Restore` somewhere, it would have *caused* your issue. If there isn't, I don't have an explanation for the behaviour. @GlennM

Comment: Oh I get it - my mistake, makes perfect sense now :-). I will take another look to see if there is a DoCmd.Restore hidden somewhere. I did remove one form the Switchboard form which resolved a similar behavior but don't think it is anywhere on the forms mentioned in my example. Will double check though! Like I said, not sure why my solution is even needed, so maybe that is the reason... Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

1. With your database open in Access 2007, click on the "Office Button" (that's the round button in the upper left hand corner of the Acces window).
2. Click on the "Access Options" at the botton right.
3. In the "Access Options" dialog box, click on the "Current Database" option from the list on the left.
4. In the "Application Options" group, locate the "Document Window options". There are two options and an check box. Select the "Operlapping Windows" option. (The "Tabbed Documents" option is the default for all Access 2007 files. For more information about this, you may want to click on the "Guide to Access 2007 User Interface" link located on the "Getting Statred with Microsoft Office Access" screen that appears when you open Access 2007 from a short cut on your desktop or from the Startup menu.)
5. After making the selecltion of the "Overlapping Windows" option and closisng the diaplog box, you will be prompted that you have to close the current database and reopen it for your changes to take effect. Selecting the "Overlapping Windows" option will cause Access to use the interface that you are more used to.